# Point of rotation appears as an ellipse when calculated from gps coordinates

Tags: gps

First question here. 
Feel free to write if I posted in the wrong place.

While rotating a ship as accurately as we can around some point within the ship, we can calculate the point of rotation from GPS data collected by a GPS receiver on the ship (the GPS is positioned some distance away from the point of rotation).

From the GPS data we gather, we find the point of rotation to be an ellipse.
Of course due to inaccuracy we cannot find the exact point of rotation from GPS satellites, but is there some physical explanation as to why the point of rotation is an ellipse and not a circle?

For reference we used a Dynamic Positioning system to calculate the point of rotation.
This was a circle.

Comment: I guess because the earth is curved.